# Why this definition for surface works?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, surfaces

> A set $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called surface of dimension $m$ and
>   class $C^k$ when every point $p\in M$ is contained in some open
>   $U\subset R^{n}$ such that $V = U\cap M$ is the image of a
>   parametrization $\phi: V_0\to V$ of dimension $m$ and class $C^k$.

But what is a parametrization?

> A parametrization of class $C^k$ and dimension $m$ of a set $V\subset
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ is an imersion $\phi:V_0\to V$ of class $C^k$ which is,
>   at the same time, an homeomorphism of the open
>   $V_0\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ under $V$

But what is an imersion?

> An imersion in the open $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ in the space
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a differentiable application $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$
>   such that for all $x\in U$, $f'(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is an
>   injective linear transformation

But why this defines a surface? What do we want to define as a surface and what we don't? My book simply throws these definitions at my face but I don't even understand why this is required to define a surface.

Is there a book that explains better why we should define surfaces this way, and why each piece of the definition is required?

**UPDATE; Why a plane is a surface by this definition?**

Comment: It does sound like you should start with a more elementary book first. Perhaps M.P. do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*?

Comment: It might be useful to go even more elementary, and learn some multivariable advanced calculus, in particular the implicit function theorem, the regular value theorem, and related topics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A surface of dimension $m$ is a surface which at every point locally looks like a piece of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

To make this definition rigorous, you need:

- A way of defining what "local" means. In our case, we'll say that a point "locally" has a behavior if there's an open set $U$ around it that has the behavior.
- A formal definition of what it means to be "locally like" $\mathbb{R}^m$.  What we mean is that (for each point) there's a map $\phi$ from a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to a neighborhood of your point. The mapping must preserve some structure of the original space $\mathbb{R}^m$, which is what you would need in order to show that the piece of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and the piece of $M$ around your point have similar structure.
- Names for the "neighborhoods" or "pieces" involved.  Let's use $p$ to refer to the point on your manifold $M$. We want to say that the point looks locally like a piece of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let's use $V$ to refer to the piece of $\mathbb{R}^m$ which it resembles. Also, if your manifold $M$ is part of a larger space $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, let's use $U$ to refer to the piece of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^N$ around your point. Then $V_0 \equiv U\cap M$ will be the piece of the *manifold* around your point. We want $\phi :V_0\rightarrow V$.
- A definition of what "structure" you want the parametrization ("resemblance") $\phi$ to preserve. Our definition says that it is in $C^k$, it's an immersion, and it's a homeomorphism.

  - It's a *homeomorphism*, which means that it matches the topological structure of  $V_0\subseteq M$ to the topological structure of $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ in a reversible way. Roughly, this means that points that are close before the mapping are close afterwards, and you can "squish" $V$ into $V_0$ and back without cutting or gluing.
  - It's in $C^k$, which means that the map is not only continuous but differentiable; you can *smoothly* transform $V$ into $V_0$.
  - It's an immersion, which formally means that it's a function whose derivative is injective. Why do we want this definition? Consider a specific 2 dimensional surface such as a sphere. Every point on this surface has a two dimensional tangent plane made of all its tangent vectors. If $V_0$ is a neighborhood of a point on this sphere, and $V$ is a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^m$, a map $\phi$ will be an injective linear map just if the tangent space of the destination point $\phi(p)$ has the same dimension as the tangent space of the original point $p$---no less! If the dimension were less, it would mean that $\phi$ distorts the manifold too much at $p$, e.g. twisting it to a point or a line.  See: [Embedding, immersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68254/embedding-immersion)

Drawing pictures of the situation helps, in my experience.

---

Intuitively, a plane is a surface because at every point it looks locally like $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Doesn't it?) Show how at every point $p$ on the plane, you can take an open neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and map it onto a piece of the plane around $p$ in a structure-preserving way.

Comment: What's a manifold?

Comment: Good question. Here, I am using that term informally to refer to the subset $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ as in your definition.

Comment: Could you explain better the part about immersions?

Comment: I didn't understand the injectivity and dimension relation

Comment: I can point to some sources. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68254/embedding-immersion . Also remember that a derivative is a kind of linear map.  Consider what it takes for a linear map to be injective; if it helps, consider what it takes for a 3x3 matrix representation of a linear map to be injective. Also you may look up the definition of matrix rank.

Comment: Wow! This is close to a perfect answer, +1!

Comment: You ask "What's a manifold?" The word "manifold" is the correct word for what you (incorrectly) refer to in your original question as a "surface". One only uses the word "surface" when the dimension $m$ is equal to $2$, so your phrase "surface of dimension $m$" is any oxymoron when $m \ne 2$. In general dimensions one uses instead the word "manifold".